# Is it possible to make a bot send messages based on a website?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

What I want to make is every time when there is something new on a website my discord bot just sends a message saying "Hey there is a new thing there". For example there is a book website and they upload new post about books and it's description and my bot just takes the text from that post online and sends it to my discord server. I hope it was clear enough. Here I have my basic discord bot code made in Python 3.9

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is working.")

client.run('not today')
```

Comment: You can use [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=task#discord-ext-tasks-asyncio-task-helpers) to run a task every x to check if the content on a site has changed. The actual checking is up to you

Comment: I think the big challenge is listen up the changes in a website and I see two alternatives: If you have access to modify the website to listen, you can integrate that website with some service like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/). On another hand if you don't have access to modify the website, you can make some service using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the website html/xml code and find some way to identify new content or whatever you want, but this way it's really hard. To build a trust listener/notifier you must control both parts.

Comment: I think more information on whether you own the website or not, because if you own it then its easier. If not then the previous two comments are possible methods (to check whether a website's content has changed every x seconds using tasks in discord.py

Answer (score 6):

*For more detail, I would suggest looking at the documentation for the [`discord.ext.tasks` module](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html), which allows you to run background tasks for you bot. This is especially handy for more personalized implementation of the framework.*

The two parts of the problem are not too difficult:

1. Create a web scraper that checks for updates within the page HTML
2. Create a background task which utilizes said web scraper.

---

### Create a web scraper

*The packages used for web scraping are completely up to the developer's desires/needs. Since `discord.py` uses `asyncio`, you should use an asynchronous parser, such as [`aiohttp`](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/), or [`requests-html`](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) as opposed to `urllib` or `requests`, which are blocking.*

#### With AIOHTTP

```py
import aiohttp

RECENT_HTML = ""

async def download_webpage():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("<url>") as response:
            if response.status != 200:
                # Notify users that the website could not be scraped

            html = await response.text()
            if html != RECENT_HTML:
                # Notify users of changes within the website
                # An HTML parser could be used to identify specific changes within the HTML
                # Or you could just tell the members that a change occurred.
            RECENT_HTML = html
```

Thse `download_webpage()` coroutine creates a session to download the webpage (substitute `"<url>"` with the actual URL of the website, then simply checks whether the webpage changed or not by comparing the page HTML to `RECENT_HTML`. `RECENT_HTML` just stores the most recent version of the HTML which was scraped, for comparison. The HTML to check against does not have to be stored as a variable, for example it can be written to a file.

If the HTML is different, you could simply notify the members or you can use an HTML parser to get the exact differences. Note that the changes may be subtle and irrelevant (e.g. the ads on the page were changed between checks), so I do recommend checking for changes within specific elements. (However, doing so is outside the scope of this question.)

Finally, a fresh copy of the page HTML is stored in the variable (or however else the most recent version of the HTML is stored).

#### With Requests-HTML

```py
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

RECENT_HTML = ""

async def download_webpage():
    asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
    response = await asession.get("<url>")
    if response.status_code != 200:
        # Notify users that the website could not be scraped
    
    html = response.html.text
    if html != RECENT_HTML:
        # Notify users of changes within the website
        # An HTML parser could be used to identify specific changes within the HTML
        # Or you could just tell the members that a change occurred.
    RECENT_HTML = html
```

---

### Create a background task

The [`discord.ext.tasks.loop` decorator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.loop) wraps around a coroutine, scheduling it as a background task that runs at a determined interval. The interval (as a float or integer) can be in seconds, minutes, hours, or a combination of the three.

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
async def my_task():
    # Do something that is repeated every 5 seconds
```

---

So, combining the two, your web scraper task may look something like this:

```py
import aiohttp
from discord.ext import tasks

RECENT_HTML = ""

@tasks.loop(hours=1)
async def download_webpage():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("<url>") as response:
            if response.status != 200:
                # Notify users that the website could not be scraped

            html = await response.text()
            if html != RECENT_HTML:
                # Notify users of changes within the website
                # An HTML parser could be used to identify specific changes within the HTML
                # Or you could just tell the members that a change occurred.
            RECENT_HTML = html
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tasks.loop` to check for news:

```
import bs4
import aiohttp
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def check_news():
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
    async with ses.get(your_url) as response:
      if response.status == 200:
        text = await response.text()
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
        #finding the news
        #if there is a new post, you can send it to spesific channel.
```

I can help further if you can share the link.

Comment: hey i think i got the right link for my bot, i am just a begginer in python and discord bot so I was wondering if you could help me a bit further. We can chat in discord my tag is voltifer#2782

Comment: Of course we can chat in discord but if we talk in here, we will help other people on this matter as well.

Comment: can you add me on discord?